# windows installer msi package: a period (.) entered in the DefaultDir column

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I am wondering what this actually means:

> For a non-root source directory, a period (.) entered in the DefaultDir column for the source directory name or the target directory name indicates the directory should be located in its parent directory without a subdirectory.

Could you give me an example as well? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Each row of the Directory table indicates a directory both at the source and the target for the installation.

There are examples of using the (.) and (:) syntax features, which show populated [Directory tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/eaca30cb-fec1-49ca-8b23-5e54c583e3e2) and resolved paths, in the MSDN documentation: [Using the Directory Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/3f2e1cc2-6b36-4615-86e6-e78485edd2f7)

There is also an example of a Directory table in the topic [Specifying Directory Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/31390138-b1d0-4f0b-9304-6e7c69e6a736) which corresponds to the layout described in the topic [Planning the Installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/8b0fb473-e19f-4427-b2a1-d0721cde9d38).

Comment: I would also recommend [a series of articles about `Directory table` from Rob Mensching](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2005/06/21/431294.aspx) (7 total).